# General logic how to dynamically load content only once reCAPTCHA v3 returns a human-like score

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, recaptcha-v3

**I only need pseudocode/general logic for this. Actual code is also fine, but general logic is enough.**

I would like to dynamically load sensitive content from a file, which is usually not accessible in other ways. Meaning, the user should interact with the website, the reCAPTCHA v3 analyzes the user's behaviour and once the behaviour appears to be human-like it gives green light to load the content into the DOM.

I would prefer to not use jQuery.

How can I accomplish this? I am using ASP.NET Core (.NET 6) for the backend and vanilla JS for the frontend.

## What I brainstormed so far

I guess I could write a controller, which listens on an endpoint for a AJAX call, but I have no idea how to write this logic and whether this would work and give the results I want. Especially how do I dynamically add the content now.

Answer (score 0):

In recaptcha you can use the attribute "data-callback" which will trigger your js function on success. for example your html code will look like:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="onReCaptchaSuccess" data-sitekey="myCode"></div>
```

In js create a function called onReCaptchaSuccess and make your ajax request to load your data there.

Comment: Don't I need to also pass a token? I'm guessing in the `onReCaptchaSuccess` function I also gotta replace the `.g-repatcha` div `innerText` or `html` then?

Comment: Also this appears to be reCAPTCHA v2 and not v3..